# Pre-qualification screening for apartment rentals on apps like Zumper. How honest should I be?

Tags: canada, retirement, renter

I'm looking to move from one - expensive - rental apartment to another, similar priced.

Now my circumstances are that I am semi-retired, starting a business and with more than enough money in the bank to cover this for a few years.  I will probably move to a cheaper city when my kids are grown.  I.e. I am not going in over my head.  My credit score is OK-ish (I rarely take out enough credit to have much of a history).

However, in these pre-qualification screening questions, the first one is:

> What is your monthly household income?
>
> Use your pre-tax income for calculations

That income is fairly low, as I tend to be very conservative in my investment goals.  At least in Canada, is there any risk in inflating that number so that I don't get screened out needlessly?

When actually applying I don't plan to say anything else than that I am retired, can afford it and can have my bank vouch for my ability to pay.  All of which are true.

The catch, at least with Zumper, is that this pre-screening declaration is shared across all prospective landlords, once I enter one.  So it's more tricky than just saying that to one 1 rental agency and seeing what comes out of it, it ends up being an up front commitment.

Any risk this can come back to bite me, in terms of burning my credibility on Zumper?  I don't see how this would be checked and then flagged as invalid, but...

Note about that [duplication](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107238/how-to-show-a-landlord-what-we-have-in-savings) remark: I **can** do as suggested in the linked answer, in fact I **have done so** in the past, with hardcopies of bank statements.

But that's at the point I am actually applying, not during the stage of a website's prescreening, *before I have any intent to rent the property*.  Not the same thing, not least in terms of id theft security.  Plus, this particular form is just a drop down declaring income to the nearest $1K/month.  No more, no less.

Comment: Is there a comments section in your profile where you could more accurately describe your situation? Also, regarding sharing your info across all prospective landlords, I assume you can update your info at any time and it would perhaps only be shared with those you apply for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a landlord what we have in savings?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107238/how-to-show-a-landlord-what-we-have-in-savings)

Comment: @nanoman Not exactly.  I **can** do as suggested, in fact I have done so in the past.  But that's at the point I am making an application, not during the stage of a website's **pre**screening.

Comment: I don't know Canadian law, but in many/most US states we can verify income, I'd rather see an honest answer to the question with explanation than have someone lie and then try to justify their lie. Reach out to Zumper and ask them how they handle situations like yours so you can answer honestly and not get rejected before consideration.

Comment: @HartCO Zumper's GenZ programmers probably didn't think of this "edge case" (which isn't actually so edgy).